# typeahead after select option from autocomplete change input box

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I'm implementing **typeahead** autocomplete selection, after click on drop down option its change the box from **From** to **To** but when I choose drop down option using **Enter key** its not change the box as above.

My input box look like this and its code is below:
[image: Figure 1]

Please tell me what should I do?

```
From: <input type="text" name="from" autocomplete="off" class="form-control inputTxtLarge inputSrc typeahead tt-query" placeholder="From: City or Airport" id="from_city" value="Delhi (India) DEL" spellcheck="false" required>

To: <input type="text" name="to" autocomplete="off" id="go_dest" class="form-control inputTxtLarge inputDest typeahead tt-query" placeholder="To: City or Airport" spellcheck="false" required>
```

javaScript function for change **From** to **To**

```
$(document).on('click', '.tt-selectable', function(){
    $( "#go_dest" ).focus();
});
```

Comment: how do you call the typeahead function - show your code pls, and which version of typeahead are u using ?

Comment: code is more long so it is not possible to show code in comment box, version is 0.11.1

Comment: i mean just the call - $("....").typeahead ....

Answer (score 0):

Typeahead has several Events for this one - here an example with jquery

```
var objTypeahead = $("#domobject").typeahead();
objTypeahead.on("typeahead:select", function(e, suggestionObject)
{
    console.log(suggestionObject);
});
```

> you can find the full list of events [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events)